Question about my ties and residency when requesting B1/B2 US visa
I'm an Iranian student / 19 male studying in Italy on a study permit. I’ve recently been accepted into HackHarvard and another competition at Georgetown, and I have a letter from HackHarvard to show at the embassy.
I’ve been living and working in Italy for a while now. I rent a house with a four-year contract, and I’m also enrolled at a university, I am working with an Italian co-founder on a startup, so I have ties to Italy.
My income is enough to cover my own expenses, but I wanna know if can I propose my father as a supporter?
Here’s my concern: my Italian residence permit has expired, but I have the renewal receipt and confirmation that it’s being processed. As you might know, the renewal process here can take forever! Will this cause any problems when applying for my U.S. visa?
and are my ties enough?
If I apply anyway and get rejected does that affect my future applications?
Travel history :

Turkey
Italy
France and Switzerland - no passport stamp


Why do you think that including your father as a sponsor would help?

@AliceRyhl my salary covers my expences but It's not enough to be proposed as financial support.

@Someonewithnoidea your salary is a signal that you have something to return for. 3rd party supporting you is a signal that you can afford overstaying. So, again, why do you think that including your father as a sponsor would help?

How established is the startup you have co-founded? Is it just a small project without a website or registration as a company? Or is it a big project where you already have employees, customers, and office space? Somewhere in between? Does your income come from this start-up, or do you also do other work? Does your father actually send you money to help you with your expenses?

The question is: can you afford this trip on your own, easily and after all your other expenses, or do you need to get your father to pay for the trip? If you can pay yourself there is no need to mention your father. If you can't then you must get your father (or someone else) to pay your expenses.

@DJClayworth my salary covers my living expences but won't cover my trip expenses, I can ask my father to deposit some money in my account or else I'm not very familiar with how to present him as my supporter, and do you think my ties are enough?
my travel is barely 3-7 days based on the competition.

@AliceRyhl no it's only in the early stages we are working with universities and some local associations.  had a beta test but nothing commercial.

Is your 4 year rental in Italy paid up in advance or month by month (not much of a tie if the latter)? Is your study course relevant to coding? Do you have a history of attending such events?

@Traveller no its month by month however like everywhere there is 6 months of rent as a deposit, yes I'm a computer engineering student and a member of several programming communities.

If you need your father's assistance to pay for this trip that is perfectly fine. It's a normal situation which US immigration have seen millions of times. It's absolutely normal for a relative to help a student with travel expenses.
You will need to submit statements of your own financial situation and statements of your father's financial situation, in order to show that he has the money to pay you. You also need a statement from him that he will contribute to your expenses, and how much.
Do not have him transfer the money until needed. Unexpected and unexplained deposits in your account do not look good.

Just to add: Iran is a "special" country for US, like just few others, so expect much more scrutiny at every step.
